# How to add karma points to users?

Tags: users

I want to add more karma points to my client's registered users but I'm trying to find an easier way of adding them. Does anyone know an easy way to add karma points to users or how to give users a specific amount of karma points if they run out of them? Is there a plug in I can install that automatically loads up karma points?

Comment: Thank you for your question, but third-party plugins/themes & plugin/theme recommendations are off-topic here on WPSE. If you're open to writing code to solve the problem, take a look at the User Meta API starting with [`update_user_meta()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta).

Comment: @DaveRomsey  so there is no easy way to add the karma points manually? I'm just trying to add them to uses.

Comment: Sorry, karma points for users are not part of the WordPress core. You'd need to code a solution or find a plugin that implements this functionality.